# $\mathbf{Set} \not \simeq \mathbf{Set}^*$ by considering $\{1, 2 \} \to \{1\}$

Tags: category-theory, alternative-proof

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498437/259262) gives a nice way of seeing why the category of sets is not isomorphic to its dual. I would like to know whether there is a proof from a certain different direction.

When considering the problem, the first idea I had was that there is precisely one arrow in $\mathbf{Set}$ going $\{1, 2\} \to \{1\}$, but two arrows in $\mathbf{Set}$ going $\{1\} \to \{1, 2\}$. Therefore, if the two categories $\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{Set}^*$ are isomorphic (via $\phi$, say, an arrow in the category of locally small categories), then $\phi$ cannot act trivially on both $\{ 1 \}$ and $\{1, 2 \}$ at the same time.

Is there a way of extending this into a proof that no such $\phi$ exists at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

In **SET** singletons are terminal objects. Then in its opposite category any singleton is an initial object. However in **SET** there is only one initial object (the empty set). This shows that the two categories are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 7):

The categories are not even equivalent.

In $\mathbf{Set}$ there exists an arrow from a terminal object to a non-terminal object -- for example one of the functions $\{1\}\to\{1,2\}$. But $\mathbf{Set}^{op}$ does not have this property, because such an arrow in $\mathbf{Set}^{op}$ would be a function from a nonempty set to the empty set.