# Isomorphism between categories and how to prove non-isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Regarding to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498425/why-is-every-category-not-isomorphic-to-its-oppositesomorphic-to-its-opposite/) topic, I have some ambiguities on the notion of isomorphism between categories, that I'll ask here:

**1-** That we can't allow the contravariant functors to be isomorphisms (as @UlrikRasmussen suggests at the first post and @TobiasKildetoft comments) between categories (e.g., $Sets$ and its dual) is because **there is no category** with its objects as categories and its arrows as ascontravariant functors (or a collection containing them). So an isomorphism (as an specific arrow) here can not be a contravariant functor.

Am I right? Or there is another reason for it?

**2-** How should we prove that two objects (here two categories) are not isomorphic. By definition, it is equivalent to state that there is no arrow from one to another for which there is an 'inverse' which their compositions make the unit arrows of the objects.
**BUT** In practice, all I can suspect is that people use some properties that are held under isomorphism between structures and show that one has the property and one doesn't have it. That is, they use some traditional way of looking at isomorohism between structures and then conclude that they are not isomorphic!

Now what's the problem here?

Please clarify me on these two questions and wait for further ones. (in the case they exist!)

Yours

Comment: 1. This isn't special to categories. We could also consider "contravariant" morphisms or isomorphisms between rings, say (reversing the multiplication), and while this is sometimes a useful thing to do we don't consider them as morphisms in the category of rings because that would just be weird. Among other things, they aren't closed under composition. 2. It's better to talk about equivalence rather than isomorphism of categories. You can prove that to categories are not equivalent by showing that various properties (e.g. having an initial or terminal object) are invariant up to  equivalence..

Comment: ...and then showing that one category has some such property while another doesn't. Nothing particularly sophisticated. I have no idea what you mean by "what's the problem here?"

Comment: @QiaochuYuan By "problem" in 2, I mean that: It's not a category theoretic context, when we go through properties that are/aren't preserved under, say, structure-preserving bijections between two categories.
That is, we go beyond pure category theory (if proper to say that). Maybe calling it a "problem" isn't good btw!

Comment: No, that certainly is pure category theory. But again, the natural notion of isomorphism for categories is equivalence, which is a bit more interesting than a structure-preserving bijection. Categories themselves naturally form a 2-category.

Answer (score 2):

(1) No, it's because contravariant functors are not morphisms in *the* (standard) category of categories.  You can in fact define a category whose objects are categories and whose morphisms include both covariant and contravariant functors, but that is not what people mean when they say "the category of categories".  People define the category of categories to include only covariant functors, so an isomorphism of categories (in the standard sense) must be a covariant functor.  (*Why* it is a good idea to define the category of categories in this way is a separate question.)

(2) Like Qiaochu, I'm not sure what "problem" you see.  To apply "traditional isomorphism invariants", you can first prove that the categorical definition of "isomorphism" coincides with the typical "structure-preserving bijection" concrete definition in your particular category, and then you prove (just as usual) that your traditional invariants are invariant under structure-preserving bijections.  Both of these steps are typically entirely straightforward, so straightforward that people talking about them often omit the details without comment.

Comment: Just a question: if there is a category whose morphisms include contravariant functors how do you compose two contravariant functors between them? More in details: if you have $F \colon C \to D$ and $G \colon D \to E$ are two contravariant functors (so $F: \colon C^\text{op} \to D$ and $G \colon D^\text{op} \to E$) what is $G \circ F$?

Comment: The composition is a covariant functor, defined by just composing what they do on objects and what they do on morphisms in the obvious way.  I said that this category would include _both_ covariant and contravariant functors, not just contravariant functors.

Comment: I see so basically is the generalization of the composition of two anti-monotone maps.... to be fair I was expecting that but I wanted to be sure, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off not thinking in terms of contravariant functors.  There are no contravariant functors; it's just a short-hand for (covariant) functors from opposite categories.  Opposite categories are just categories.  The category $Cat$ of (small, say) categories and functors between them certainly includes functors, and even isomorphisms, from opposite categories.  In fact, every isomorphism could be considered an isomorphism with a "contravariant" functor   given the above definition: $F : C \cong D$ is $F : (C^{op})^{op} \cong D$.

Slightly less trivially, there are plenty of categories that are isomorphic to their opposites.  In fact, this is true for every groupoid (a category where all arrows are isomorphisms).  All Tobias was saying is that an isomorphism is defined in terms of functors, and a "contravariant functor from $C$ to $D$" is simply not a functor from $C$ to $D$.  (It's a functor from $C^{op}$ to $D$.)

As Qiaochu Yuan says in the comments, isomorphism is not the best notion to use when talking about categories.  It's too rigid.  Hence, the notion of equivalence of categories which is weaker than isomorphism.  It is, in a sense, "isomorphism up to isomorphism".

Your understanding about how to prove a lack of isomorphism is more or less correct.  You can certainly attempt to disprove the existence of an isomorphism directly, but usually, as you say, properties that would be preserved by isomorphism are used such as the existence of (co)limits.