# An example of a direct product that is not a Cartesian product

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there an (easy to understand) example of a product that is not a Cartesian product?

In modern mathematics one learns first that products of "spaces" are Cartesian products, for instance, products of topological spaces, vector spaces, modules, groups. The elements of these products have "coordinates". which are familiar from linear algebra.

Then one learns that Cartesian products are "direct products" which have a uniqueness-property (if you are unlucky, they call it the "universal mapping property".

Then one meets Category Theory and there one learns that direct products are products with the "Universal Mapping Property".
Of course one accepts this development. But is it ever made clear why there is this development? That is why:

I would like to have an example that shows that the Cartesian product is not enough to construct products in general and a more general definition of the product, that is the categorical product, is needed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by direct product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

What you call "direct product" is usually just called a "product". The dual notion is that of a coproduct. Products and coproducts are the easiest examples of limits and colimits, in case you wanted to go more in depth. When you say "Cartesian product", you mean a product (in some concrete category) that has as underlying set the Cartesian product of the sets. A concrete category is a category in which the objects are sets with some extra structure and the morphisms are functions between sets that preserve this structure. These are the most common categories at the beginning, but they are by no means alone in the categorical world. Yours is a fairly common perplexity, because in all the easiest examples of concrete categories (sets, groups, $R−$modules, topological spaces,...) the product "is" a Cartesian product. So let us see an example where this is not the case. It will not really be a concrete category (there are some concrete categories with more interesting products, but they often require more background), but at least the objects will be sets. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)#Examples) you can find more examples.

**Relations** are "generalizations" of functions: given sets $A$ and $B$, the graph of a function $f \colon A \to B$ is a subset of $A \times B$ with some specific properties: every element $a \in A$ appears in exactly one element $(a,b)$, namely the one with $b=f(a)$. Instead, a relation $r \colon A \to B$ is just **any** subset of $A \times B$. One might require other properties (you can have a look at equivalence relations or order relations, for instance), but we deal with **all** relations here. You might have noticed that a relation has no preferred direction: a subset of $A \times B$ is "the same" as a subset of $B \times A$. An element of $A$ might have multiple "images" under a relation (or one, or none at all), so instead of writing $r(a)=b$ (which would not make sense), we write $(a,b) \in r$. Composition works "exactly as for functions" (if you think about it): given a second relation $s \colon B \to C$ we say that $(a,c) \in s \circ r$ if and only if there is some $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in r$ and $(b,c) \in s$. Now we can consider the category with sets as objects and relations as morphisms. We call this (somewhat confusingly) the **category of relations**. This has the usual category of sets with functions as a subcategory (the objects are the same, but there are more relations than functions), but it behaves quite differently, as we are about to see.

Extra questions:

1. what is the identity relation of a set $A$?
2. when is a relation an isomorphism (i.e., when does it have a left and right inverse)?

I claim that the product of some sets $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ in the category of relations "is" the **disjoint union** $\sqcup A_i$ of all the $A_i$. The "product map" (or "projection") from $\sqcup A_i$ to a specific $A_j$ is $r_j := \{(a,a) \mid a \in A_j \}$. Note that the set $\sqcup A_i$ is in general much smaller than the Cartesian product: the disjoint union of two lines is just two lines, their Cartesian product is a whole plain. It is a very instructive exercise to convince yourself that this is indeed the product, i.e., that if a set $P$ has a given relation $p_j$ to each $A_j$, then there is a unique relation $q$ from $P$ to $\sqcup A_i$ such that $p_j = r_j \circ q$ for all $j \in I$.

Solution: $q = \cup p_i$.

Further exercises:

1. show that $\sqcup A_i$ is also the coproduct in the category of relations (and, this time, this agrees with the coproduct of sets)
2. explain (intuitively) why the Cartesian product is not the product in the category of relations, and/or why the disjoint union is not the product in the category of sets with functions

Comment: How does that answer OP’s question?

Comment: I understand your comment, but I have no way to know which example would be easiest for the OP, a priori. So I will only give details about what he asks. And maybe the OP had just not found the list because he was looking for the wrong word.

Comment: Then perhaps it would have been better to comment and ask for clarification. Without knowing what OP means by direct product, and assuming Cartesian product is meant to be categorical product, there is no way to properly answer the question.

Comment: I think that by "direct product" he means categorical product, and by "Cartesian product" he means a categorical product (in some concrete category) that has as underlying set the Cartesian product of the sets. It is a fairly common perplexity, because in all the easiest examples (sets, groups, $R-$modules, topological spaces,...) the product "is" a Cartesian product.

Comment: @57Jimmy You should probably explain how you're interpreting the question in the answer.

Comment: @57Jimmy, yes, that is what I meant: the categorical product and the Cartesian product. I would like to have an example that shows that the Cartesian product is not enough to construct products and a more general definition of the product is needed. I would appreciate if you give me more details, if you want. And I am sorry for my lack of "categorical experience".

Comment: @Steenis No need to be sorry at all ;) I will expand the answer then

Comment: @Steenis You do know what is the general definition of a product, right? I mean, the "universal" definition.

Comment: @Steenis The questions and exercises are not extremely easy, if you are new to the subject, but you might want to give them a try at some point: I think they would be useful.

Comment: @57Jimmy. I have a basic knowledge of the theory of categories as an amateur. I have read the chapter on Categories and Functors of “Rotman - An Introduction to Homological Algebra (1st edition, 1979)”; the half of “Roman - An Introduction to the Language of Category Theory (2017)”, including chapter 3 on universality; “Freyd - Abelian Categories (1964)” until about page 54, after that I became stuck; some in “Herrlich – Category Theory (1973)”; and more. So I have some knowledge on UMP, sum, product, difference kernel, tensor product, but I am not a professional. And I am poor in examples.

Comment: @57Jimmy. Thank you for your example, I am still working on it. It will take a while.

Comment: No worries. I can write you some of the solutions in the following comment, just don't look at them before trying ;)

Comment: The identity relation is just the identity function (it is the unique relation that you can compose right and left with every other relation without changing them). A relation is an isomorphism in the category of relations if and only if it's a bijective function. So we have more morphisms, but not more isomorphisms as in the category of sets. The coproduct is the same as the product because relations don't have a "direction" and the two notions are "symmetric". In the category of sets the problem is that we do not have a nice canonical map from the disjoint union of some sets to a single set.

Comment: @57Jimmy: I think that I understand your example. I could answer 1. and 2. of your extra questions. Using your solution $q = \cup p_i$ I could prove that the disjoint union $\sqcup A_i$ is the product of the $A_i$. You said that product and coproduct are “symmetric” and relations have no “direction”. I assumed that you meant that “Rel” and the opposite of “Rel” are the same. Realizing that, it was easy to show that the disjoint union is also the coproduct of the $A_i$. Only item 2. of the further exercises is still too hard for me. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @57Jimmy: Can I say that “Set” and the opposite of “Set” are not the same, because the opposite of a function need not be a function, or is that too bold?

Comment: Your reasoning with the opposite category is exactly what I meant. Yes, you can say so!

Comment: Although usually the right notion is for categories to be *equivalent*, not *isomorphic*, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498425/why-is-every-category-not-isomorphic-to-its-opposite) post might be interesting, also because the answer introduces the category corresponding to a poset, which gives many examples of categories where the product is not a cartesian product (if only for the fact that there are no underlying sets but only points and arrows)

Comment: As for the second exercise: the Cartesian product is in general not isomorphic (as a set) to the disjoint union, hence it cannot be the right product in Rel, because we have shown that isomorphisms in Rel are the same as in Set.

Comment: I think (but I acknowledge that Rel is not the easiest category to think about) that the problem is that you have many possible choices for a relation $q$ from the disjoint union to the Cartesian product such that $p_j \circ q = r_j$, where the $p_j$ are the projections of the Cartesian product. That's another reason why it is not the right product in Rel.